# Convert NSString to Unsigned long

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am having `NSString` value which I want to convert in `unsigned long`. I used code below

```
NSString *updateId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tweet updateId]];

NSLog(@"%@",[tweet updateId]);
unsigned long  tweetId = [updateId longLongValue];
NSLog(@"ButtonPressed: .......%llu",tweetId);
```

But it is not returning correct value...

Comment: What does it return? And what's the data-type returned by updatedId?

Comment: updateId is returning NSstring.. And my output is 65278530740695040
2011-05-03 12:47:56.704 MiniTwit[2949:207] ButtonPressed: .......6071468025620606976

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Cocoa way would be to use `[NSNumberFormater]`[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%lu", [[formatter numberFromString:updateId] unsignedLongValue]);
[formatter release];
```

What's the the type of [tweet updateId]?
Does it contain any localization (e.g. thousand separators)?
If so, you could configure the `NSNumberFormatter` instance with `setLocale:`

Comment: NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"%lu", [[formatter numberFromString:updateId] unsignedLongValue]);
[_engine deleteUpdate:formatter];
[formatter release];  not working giving warning

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in another NSString then? You can directly pass [tweet updateId] to numberFromString: .

Comment: warning is passing argument 1 of 'deleteupdate' makes integer from pointer without a case...      method is
- (NSString *)deleteUpdate:(unsigned long)updateID

Comment: does your deleteUpdate: method take an unsigned long value? Pass [formatter unsignedLongValue]

Comment: You are directly passing formatter. This can't work. Get the unsigned long value with [formatter unsignedLongValue]

Comment: [_engine deleteUpdate:[[formatter numberFromString:[tweet updateId]] unsignedLongLongValue] ];
used this and this is returning correct value.but update is not deleted..thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `atol` function from the C stdlib:

```
unsigned long tweetId = atol( [ updateId cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding ] );
```

And by the way, your NSLog should be `lu`, not `llu`.

Comment: Which header file I should include? It is giving warning NSString may not respond to CStringUsingEncoding

Comment: Are you using CStringUsingEncoding or cStringUsingEncoding? methods are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long tweetId = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[updateId integerValue]] unsignedLongValue];
```